# I am sorry to keep you waiting

Tags: exam-questions

> I am sorry _________________

A. **for keeping** you waiting

B. **to keep** you waiting

C. **for keep** you waiting

The given answer is **B.**  (to keep you waiting)

Does infinitive is required after **sorry**? Why is A or C not correct?

Comment: As an aside, your question should be "**Is** it required", not "does it is required", because we don't use *do* with "is" questions in English.

Answer (score 2):

C is definitely wrong: with a [few exceptions](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive/) prepositions cannot be followed by a bare infinitive. They either require to infinitives or gerunds. Which leaves us with A and B.

***Sorry*** is an adjective that is more often used ***not** before a noun*. It can be followed by a to infinitive or by a gerund but with different meanings:

> [not before noun] *feeling sad and sympathetic*
>
> - ***sorry (to see, hear***, etc.)
>    We're ***sorry to hear*** that your father's in the hospital again.
>
> [not before noun] *feeling sad and ashamed **about something that has been done***
>
> - *sorry (**for** something/**doing** something)*
>    He says he's really ***sorry for taking*** the car without asking. ([Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/sorry_1))

Your sentence is an instance of the first meaning, not the second (the second enhances that the action you are saying 'sorry' for is past). You would say

> *Sorry to keep you waiting*

when you are late for an appointment, to people who have been waiting for you until the moment of speech. If the waiting was done in the past, you could probably say:

> Sorry for keeping you waiting last week in the park, I just couldn't make it.

This use is [more rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry%20to%20keep%20you%20waiting%2C%20sorry%20for%20keeping%20you%20waiting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorry%20to%20keep%20you%20waiting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorry%20for%20keeping%20you%20waiting%3B%2Cc0) and would need more context. So yes, without any other context, your sentence B is correct.

Comment: I agree with this analysis but with one exception. Rather than just being for a context in the past “sorry for keeping you waiting” is also used for ongoing contexts. eg: shop assistant is still dealing with customer A but looks over to customer B and says, “Sorry for keeping you waiting. I won’t be long.”